# Windows lost the location of all the files on my hard drive

Tags: windows, file-recovery

One day out of the blue Windows 7 began acting buggy on my machine so I attempted to reboot, never to be able to boot up again. In an effort to avoid wasting my time I replaced the drive with a new one and stored my old drive away.

Now I am attempting to recover the files, as I found out at the time of the (begin air quotes) failure (end air quotes) all my files were completely fine. They were somehow lost on the drive for no apparent reason. Using some file undelete software I was able to see my files.

Unfortunately the directory tree is lost, which is a problem for me.

Is there any way to repair the file index or something?